# Prove that if $\|f(x)\|\to 0$, then $f(x)\to 0$ using the $(\epsilon,\delta )$-definition of limit

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, epsilon-delta

Could anyone help me with this proof?

> Prove that $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)=0$  whenever $\lim_{x\to a} \|f(x)\|=0$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$
>
> Where $f(x)$ is a vector function and $\|f(x)\|$ is the vector norm.

My try:

I let $\|f(x)-0\|< \delta_1$  whenever $\|x-a\|< \epsilon_1$  for the first function.

$\|f(x)-0\|< \delta_2$  whenever $\|x-a\|< \epsilon_2$   for the second function.

Hence $f(x)< \|f(x)\| < \delta_2 =\epsilon_2$.

Is my proof correct? Could anyone explain? Thanks.

Comment: No. Note that `f(x) < a`for some real number `a` is meaningless since `f(x)`is a vector and (except when `n = 1`) there is no (canonical) order on `R^n`.

Answer (score 2):

We are required to prove this result only when $ \lim_{x \to a}||f(x)|| = 0 $ and so we can assume this.

So Let $\epsilon \gt 0$ be an arbitrary quantity. We must now find a corresponding $\delta$ such that $ ||f(x) - 0 || \lt \epsilon$ whenever $||x - a|| \lt \delta$. Note that since a norm is non-negative,

$$ ||f(x) - 0 || = ||f(x) || = \left|{(||f(x) ||)}\right| =  \left|{(||f(x) ||)  - 0}\right| $$

Since we know that $ \lim_{x \to a}||f(x)|| = 0 $ for any $\epsilon \gt 0\ $ **there is** a $\delta \gt 0$ such that $$ ||x - a|| \lt \delta \implies \left|{(||f(x) ||)  - 0}\right| \lt \epsilon \implies ||f(x) - 0 || \lt \epsilon$$

$\mathscr Q.E.D.$